# Javascript List objects in an array that contain a value in nested array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, big-o

I have an array of colors and I have an array of objects. Each object contains its own array of colors.

The array of colors:

```
colors = [
  'yellow',
  'blue',
  'red',
  'green',
  'purple',
  'brown',
  'fuscia',
  'grey',
  'beige',
  'orange',
]
```

The array of objects:

```
paintings = [{
    name: 'The Wind',
    rating: '25',
    colors: [
      'orange',
      'blue',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'The Sons',
    rating: '8',
    colors: [
      'red',
      'green',
      'yellow',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Freedom',
    rating: '16',
    colors: [
      'grey',
      'yellow',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Space',
    rating: '50',
    colors: [
      'purple',
      'green',
      'orange',
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to make each of the colors in the colors array an array in itself and each new color array will contain the painting objects that contain the color in its own colors array. Also, each of these objects will be ordered from highest to lowest rating. I need to end up with something like this:

```
yellow = [{
    name: 'Freedom',
    rating: '16',
    colors: [
      'grey',
      'yellow',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'The Sons',
    rating: '8',
    colors: [
      'red',
      'green',
      'yellow',
    ]
  }
]

green = [{
  name: 'Space',
  rating: '50',
  colors: [
    'purple',
    'green',
    'orange',
  ]
} {
  name: 'The Sons',
  rating: '8',
  colors: [
    'red',
    'green',
    'yellow',
  ]
}]

orange = [{
  name: 'Space',
  rating: '50',
  colors: [
    'purple',
    'green',
    'orange',
  ]
} {
  name: 'The Wind',
  rating: '25',
  colors: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
  ]
}]
```

And so on...

The above data is obviousy dummy data. I'm actually looping through a very large array. I've extracted the colors array by looping through the objects, flattening the array with `flat()` and creating a new colors array with `Set()` so I could have a list of colors to look up within each object.

So, how could the above be achieved in the most efficient way?

**Additional Info for solution:**

I ended up grouping the array after sorting the original data in the folliwng way:

```
paintings.forEach((i) => {
    paintings.sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating)
})

const colorGroup = colors.map((color) => ({
    [color]: paintings
    .filter((painting) => painting.colors.includes(color))
}));
```

Then I am limiting to displaying only 25 from my `vue-for` loop:

```
<div v-for="painting in colorGroup.slice(0, 25)">
    {{ painting }}
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var paintings = [{
    name: 'The Wind',
    rating: '25',
    colors: [
      'orange',
      'blue',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'The Sons',
    rating: '8',
    colors: [
      'red',
      'green',
      'yellow',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Freedom',
    rating: '16',
    colors: [
      'grey',
      'yellow',
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Space',
    rating: '50',
    colors: [
      'purple',
      'green',
      'orange',
    ]
  }
];
var colors = [
  'yellow',
  'blue',
  'red',
  'green',
  'purple',
  'brown',
  'fuscia',
  'grey',
  'beige',
  'orange',
];

const colorObj = colors.map((color) => ({
  [color]: paintings.filter((painting) => painting.colors.includes(color)).sort((a, b) => b.rating - a.rating)
}));

console.log(colorObj);
```

Comment: One more question, what can I add to this combination to sort the paintings by rating, from highest to lowest? I'm trying to get .sort() in there but I'm failing to get the right syntax to compare the ratings.

Comment: Hoping you want to sort just inner arrays of colors right? Find the edited answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ... i just threw it together...

```
const colors = [
    'yellow',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'green',
    'purple',
    'brown',
    'fuscia',
    'grey',
    'beige',
    'orange',
]

const paintings = [
    {
        name: 'The Wind',
        rating: '25',
        colors: [
            'orange',
            'blue',
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'The Sons',
        rating: '8',
        colors: [
            'red',
            'green',
            'yellow',
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Freedom',
        rating: '16',
        colors: [
            'grey',
            'yellow',
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'Space',
        rating: '50',
        colors: [
            'purple',
            'green',
            'orange',
        ]
    }
]

const resultObject = {}

colors.forEach(color => {
  paintings.forEach(painting => {
    if (painting.colors.includes(color)){
      if(!resultObject[color])
        resultObject[color] = []
      resultObject[color].push(painting)
    }
  })
})

console.log(resultObject)
```

Comment: You can test it here... if you want...https://playcode.io/641719/

Comment: This was very helpful, it does work! Thank you! Though I do think think that the combination of map, filter and includes may be more efficient. What do you think? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes there are many ways to write this snippet. This was just something that I did super fast without using many brain cells. Hopefully you can use it as inspiration.

Comment: You are right that there are many ways! Thank you again!! :)

Comment: One more question, what can I add to this combination to sort the paintings by rating, from highest to lowest? I'm trying to get .sort() in there but I'm failing to get the right syntax to compare the ratings.